# calculate latitude and longitude using python

Tags: python, geolocation

I have a question that I now know is not that simple.  I want to calculate the lon and lat of a point,  based on my own lat and lon, my distance to that point and to which direction it is from where I am.

So basically, lets say for example I am at lon : 20, lat : 30.  And I have a point that is around 10 meters to north east from my position ( 45 degrees , north is 0).  I want to determine the lon and lat of that point.  Is this feasible in python?